# MYSQL one to many JOIN

Tags: sql, mysql

I have this query and I need to include another join on a table called "likes" where updates.id = likes.update_id. There will be 0 or more matches on this join.

```
"SELECT * FROM users 
INNER JOIN updates ON users.remote_id=updates.owner_id 
ORDER BY updates.status_time DESC LIMIT 50"
```

This is probably fairly simple, but I haven't been able to find any examples for this kind of query.

The situation is basically that I'm displaying a list of items. I do a join on the users table to grab the user who created each item. I also need to do a join on the "likes" tables to display the 0+ people who liked each item.

---

EDIT: My Solution

Ok, here's the successful join and combining of duplicate results (due to the fact that there are multiple "likes" for each update) using GROUP_CONCAT.

```
"SELECT   users.*,updates.update_id,updates.content,updates.status_time,
GROUP_CONCAT(likes.liker SEPARATOR ',') AS liked_by 
FROM updates 
LEFT OUTER JOIN likes ON updates.update_id = likes.update_id 
JOIN users ON users.remote_id = updates.owner_id 
GROUP BY updates.update_id 
ORDER BY updates.status_time DESC 
LIMIT 200"
```

Comment: You claim to be ordering by updates.time, but there is no 'time' field in the result - what gives there?

Comment: Also, it would be helpful to have the complete list of columns for each of the three tables.  If there is a users.id column as well as an updates.id column, you might be seeing just users.id even though the join is on updates.id (one of the main problems with non-unique column names).

Comment: Yeah, the non-unique column names were causing my confusion. I figured it out and updated the original post with the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM users 
LEFT OUTER JOIN updates ON users.remote_id=updates.owner_id
INNER JOIN likes ON <join condition here>
ORDER BY updates.time DESC LIMIT 50
```

Will that work?

If not, can you clarify what exactly your question is? Does the query you have not work?

Comment: If there are zero or more matches, think "LEFT OUTER JOIN".

Comment: Ah. That makes more sense, then.

Comment: A left join in mysql is always an outer join, and just a join is always an inner join. No need to use 'outer' or 'inner' iirc.

Comment: No need, but it makes the behavior more explicit.

Answer (score 1):

if you have a 1 to n relation the you should use a LEFT JOIN , i mean if there's only 1 user and many likes.user_id you should doit with the following way

"SELECT * FROM users LEFT JOIN updates ON (users.remote_id=updates.owner_id) ORDER BY updates.time DESC LIMIT 50"

this way you'd get all the updates from a certain user :)

cheers